# What is the type of the right hand side of the assignment operator (string)?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how the assignment Operator knows what the data type of the right hand side of the Assignment Operator is.

```
string x = "foo"
```

Those are the Signatures I've found in the XCode Clang string file.

```
basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& str);
basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& str)
    noexcept(
         allocator_type::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value &&
         is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value);
basic_string& operator=(const value_type* s);
basic_string& operator=(value_type c);
basic_string& operator=(initializer_list<value_type>);
```

Which one of these are invoked?

Any explanation appreciated!

Comment: `string x = "foo"` utilizes the constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: If look inside class `string` we find it is a templated class which overloads the `=` operator like this for example: `basic_string& operator = (const E *s);` Where `s` is a pointer to generic type.

Comment: @Raindrop7 If the code were `string x; x = "foo";`, then the assignment operator comes into play.  However `string x = "foo";` is construction, not assignment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Ok that is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side has type `const char[4]`, and the constructor

```
string(const char* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

is called, with the decay of `const char[4]` to `const char*`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string for a full list of constructors.

Note that initialization in the form `T x = i;` always calls a constructor, not an assignment operator. A constructor gives an object its initial value, whereas an assignment operator replaces a value that already existed in an object.

Comment: Where is Allocator defined?

Comment: @user1767754 It is one of the template parameters of `std::basic_string`. In the case of `std::string` the default of `std::allocator<char>` is used.

Comment: Thanks Brian, sorry for bothering you, i've just couldn't get a minimal example Running. Can you write a minimal example, where you can show this constructor works when string x = "123" is given?

Comment: @user1767754 I don't understand your question. Are you asking for *proof* that that particular constructor is called?

Comment: Oh no, just a dummy "string" class with this dummy constructor (with the above signature) that is callable.